# A concise equivalent of a phrase meaning "to be pulled in turns by two subjects"

Tags: british-english

I am writng a personal statement for a degree in game development and would like to begin with a decisive and concise statement.
I wanted to express something like:

> before discovering myself in game development I was torn apart by arts and science in turns

Can you help me rephrase this in proper english? All suggestions of strong statements of simillar meaning are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the word "juxtaposed" somehow, although I wouldn't know how to word it exactly. Perhaps "I was torn between arts and science". However, I think you mean to say that you "dabbled" in in both subjects, "attracted by" is another possibility, I suppose. All in all it is a matter of choice, but your clause "I was torn apart by arts and science in turns", is definitely not the meaning you wish to convey. I'll think it over some more.

Comment: Thanks @JCG that was informative already. I'd love to hear some more.

Answer (score 2):

***torn between***

Definition of “torn between something and something” in American English - *Cambridge Dictionaries Online (English Dictionary*):

"​finding it very ​difficult to ​choose between two ​possibilities"

Example from *Cambridge Dictionary*: "She’s torn between her loyalty and her ​desire to ​tell the ​truth."

The OP asked specifically for British English.  British English and American English seem to agree on the usage of **torn between**, as evidenced by *MacMillan Dictionary* giving following for both:

"Unable to decide which of two people or things you want most.  Many women feel torn between having a family or a career."    http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/torn-between

Your sentence would then read ".....I was torn between the arts and science."  I don't think you need the phrase "in turn".

Comment: Thanks. A naitive british speaker found torn apart too heavy although he did not know how to improve it.

Comment: Oh I missed your point in the previous answer. Now I see. Torn between sounds much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative to ***torn between***, you could say that you ***oscillated between art and science*** or that you ***wavered between art and science***. Both of these would mean that you swung or swayed back and forth between the two subjects.